# Onblur Event triggered by lookup button

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a bit of onblur event that occurs when i leave a text box unfortunately the box after that is a lookup finder which causes the onblur event to occur again and messes up the event values. Does anyone know how to filter out the javascript from the lookup button. This normally happens when someone tabs too fast through the boxes but it occurs and is more than tedious.

Comment: what about doing an "onchange" event instead?

Answer (score 1):

Ended up finding out the problem and solution. Using `tagName` i was able to check what object was making the call.